# BASH shell variables dropping some newlines

Tags: bash, variables, newline

When capturing BASH output, apparently BASH deletes trailing blank lines.
For example, this:

```
$ VAR=$(echo -e '\n\n\n\n')
```

appears to leave VAR with a single newline, as can be seen in any number of ways, e.g. this one:

```
$ od -c <<< "$VAR"
0000000  \n
0000001
```

Interestingly, the phenomenon is not confined to capturing output.  This somewhat devious experiment:

```
$ VAR="$(echo -e 'x\nx\nx\nx\n')"
$ VAR="${VAR//x/}"
od -c <<< "$VAR"
0000000  \n  \n  \n  \n
0000004
```

shows what I want / expect, creating 4 x/newline pairs and deleting the 4 intervening X's.  It also verifies that shell variables can contain adjacent newlines, if there was any doubt.
However this experiment:

```
V2="$VAR@$VAR"
od -c <<< "$V2"
0000000  \n  \n  \n   @  \n  \n  \n  \n
0000010
```

reveals that one newline is lost from the first occurrence of $VAR.  NOT what I want or expect.  And surprisingly NOT deleting the trailing newlines like the original problem capturing output.

In my application, I need the output to be precisely correct, but I have searched in vain for some way to turn off this "helpful" feature (or is it a bug?).  I have not been able to play with this and find a workaround either, other than by using a kludge, e.g. capturing output that always includes an added line of non-blank text, such as:

```
VAR=$(some program ; echo "EOF")
```

This behavior is on a Debian 10 system with BASH 5.0.3, but I have also verified the same behavior on BASH 4.4.12.  My guess is that it may have been around a long time.

I wonder if anyone knows how to get BASH to keep newlines in variables with the same integrity that it does every other character?

Comment: Yes, you are describing the well known and well documented behavior of command substitutions: they strip trailing newlines. The kludge is the conventional workaround.

Comment: Slightly less well-known is that a here-string always *adds* a newline, since it is intended to be equivalent to a one-line here document, which always ends in a newline.

Comment: And how about the example I listed where an interior newline is dropped on variable assignment with no command substitution?  is that also a well known phenomenon?

Comment: The newline was dropped when you *assigned* to `VAR`. `V2` has 3 newlines on either side of the `@`; the here string adds the 4th newline when you feed the value to `od`.

Comment: The "od" output suggests that there are 4 newlines in VAR unless you are suggesting that the <<< operation adds an extra newline??  I think you are saying that a variable assignment drops one extra trailing newline, even though command assignment drops many, and you are also saying that <<< adds one back?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying. The here string is equivalent to a here document with one line, and a here document always ends with a newline. Try `printf '%s' "$VAR" | od -c`.